# Cant find params (id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not really sure what going on or why the the provider id is comming back nil and it only comes back nil when trying to render provider_patient_access_path. I add a new pages to providers so the way it should be is localhost:3000/providers/id/patient_access

[image: error message]

```
   <!-- PROVIDERS SIDE MENU -->

    <%= link_to provider_patient_access_index_path(@provider.id) do %>
        <div class="side-menu-item">
        <div class="side-menu-icon" data-id="<%= @provider.id %>"><div id="side-menu-icon-search"></div></div>
        <div id="side-menu-item-text-patient-profiles" class="side-menu-item-text">Patient Access</div>
        </div><!--side-menu-item-->
    <% end %>

    <!-- ROUTES -->
    resources :providers do 
        resources :patient_access, only: [:index]
    end

    <!-- PROVIDERS_CONTROLLER -->
   class PatientAccessController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @provider = Provider.find(params[:provider_id])
        @active_patients = @provider.lists
        authorize @provider
    end
end
    end
```

Comment: Do you see any thing wrong with my code that could possibily lead to why :provider_id is coming back nil? I also update my code to what i recently have right now. There is also a image of the error

Answer (score 2):

With those routes set up the path is going to be:

```
/providers/:id/patient_access(.format)
```

For this reason `params[:provider_id]` returns `nil` since it isn't provided, however `params[:id]` should return the correct value.

You can check your routes by visiting a non-existent URL/route in the development environment. For example http://localhost:3000/asdf. Or you can output them into the terminal using the command:

```
bundle exec rails routes
```

For more details about routing check the guide [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have checked my routes and i have tried using params[:id] in my patient_access method in the controller but it's still coming back as nil

Comment: Can you show us the incoming parameters by placing `byebug` as the first line of your *index* method? Then when the execution stops type `params`. Copy the output here in the comments, or add it to the question. To continue execution type `c`.

Comment: I also noticed you edited the question and changed the routes, so I'm not sure if this answer still applies. From the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YMwt.png) that you provided you can tell that `@provider` isn't set. That's whats raises the current error.

Comment: the same answer still applies. I trying to see if it was something with my route but i guess it's not. here is the output of when i select params "<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"patients", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>"

Comment: I didn't notice the image attached to the question when writing the answer. From what is shown it seems like you don't set `@provider` correctly in ***PatientsController#index***. Could you add the contents of the method to the question? You are currently showing the content of *PatientAccessController#index*.